# What happens if I don't pass the second parameter to std::vector's constructor?

Tags: c++, stl, initialization, stdvector, construct

We can create std::vector in this way:

```
std::vector<int> numbers(n, value);
```

It is possible **not to pass** the second parameter to the constructor.
But **are we guaranteed** that if we create std::vector of ints' it will be filled with zeroes?

Comment: It will use `T{}` (i.e. `int{}`, which actually resolves to `0` in your case) to determine the value for initialization.

Answer (score 1):

If the initializer is not explicitly specified, the objects are value initialized using the construction `T()`. For fundamental types, as for example the type `int`, it means zero-initialization.

So, this declaration:

```
std::vector<int> numbers(n);
```

Is, in fact, equivalent to:

```
std::vector<int> numbers(n, 0);
```

Here is a demonstration program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
        << ( std::vector<int>( 10, 0 ) == std::vector<int>( 10 ) )
        << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
true
```